# Elasticsearch query by value in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I got the following document indexed in ES6:

```json
{
  "id": 1234,
  ...,
  "images": [
    {
      "id": 1703805,
      ...,
      "language_codes": [],
      "ingest_source_ids": [123]
    },
    {
      "id": 2481938,
      ...,
      "language_codes": ["EN"],
      "ingest_source_ids": [1,2,3]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `images` object is mapped as `nested`.

I can find the document just fine using this query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "images",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "images.ingest_source_ids": 123
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if I instead wanna find via `languages_codes` I do not find document:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "images",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "images.language_codes": "EN"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`ingest_source_ids` has been in the documents since day one. The `language_codes` field has been added later. I do recall something about Elasticsearch doing some magic mapping with the initial documents, but on the other hand as far as I can read in the documentation, there's no special mapping needed for arrays - all fields can contain arrays as long as all keys are same type.

In this case it works fine with all keys being numeric in `ingest_source_ids`, but `language_codes` are also always strings, so should be same case.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not explicitly defined any index mapping for `language_codes`, then by default it will be indexed as :

```
 "language_codes": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

**Considering that you are using the [`term` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html), you must utilize this query on the `keyword` type field in order for the query term to match the exact term documents.**

Replace your query with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "images",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "images.language_codes.keyword": "EN"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver - do you know why using `.keyword` returns many identical documents? I got a document with three images all containing the language code `EN` which results in 3 results instead of just the one unique document?

Comment: @mtrolle using `.keyword` will give you all the documents that have `language_codes` = `"EN"`. But is it like you are getting duplicate documents and you want to get only 1 unique document based on a particular field ?

Comment: Turned out to be wrongful data expectations - thanks @ESCoder.